# Throw new ArgumentException

Tags: c#, asp.net, throws

In my code, how can i make it possible to show a alert box popping out ? i tried to replay throws new argument exception and add in                                                                        Response.Write("alert('NOT Successful');");
but it shows that i have syntax error near")". Please help me if you know .thanks in an advance .

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Page.Request.QueryString["hasProducts"].Equals("true"))
        {
            ArrayList al = Session["SelectedProducts"] as ArrayList;

            if (al == null)            
               throw new ArgumentException("A product list is required.");


            if (al.Count < 1)           
                throw new ArgumentException("No products selected");


            string inStatement = string.Empty;
            int len = al.Count;
            int count = 1;
            foreach (string item in al)
            {
                inStatement = inStatement + "'" + item + "'";
                if (count < len) { inStatement = inStatement + ","; }
                count++;
                //List<string> list = new ArrayList<string>(item.Split(','));

                //item.Split(',');
            }
            //List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(al.split(","));
            // inStatement = inStatement.Substring(0, inStatement.Length - 2);

            //Product aProd = new Product();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Product_ID in (" + inStatement + ")", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            con.Open();
            adp.Fill(ds, "Products");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
          //  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            //GridView1.DataBind(); 
            DataList1.DataSource = ds;
            DataList1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Need some more info on your error description. Looks like some syntax issue. Do provide more details

Comment: Side note, you may want to look into EntityFramework or NHibernate, your code is prone to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RegisterStartUpScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx) to add javascript to your page

```
string message = "alert('NOT Successful');";
 this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"myAlert",message,true);
```

Comment: Hi dear. I have used your code. But it seems that i cant even display an alert box. It will just throw exception

Comment: @Ng Jing what is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try the below code snippet, If you are having issue with syntax in `Response.Write`:

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('The following errors have occurred: \n" + strErrorDesc + " .');</script>");
```

Else please provide the complete code snippet.